# Hive IsType() UDF

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

Is there an easy way of determing if a field is of type array in a hive query?

E.g.

`SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN table2 ON (IS_TYPE(column) = 'array' AND array_contains(column, 'value1')`

Comment: Couldn't you just describe table or table2 to determine what type 'column' is?

Comment: I could have done, but i wanted the logic to be within the query itself as it would mean a user would have to do the lookup of the field before running a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by creating a UDF and doing a match on the type

```
def is_array(v: Any) : Boolean = {
  if (v == null)
    return false

  if (v.getClass.getSimpleName == "ArrayBuffer") {
     return true
  }

 return false
```

}